# I spilled yogurt on my car leather seats. What is the best way to remove it?

Tags: cleaning, car

I spilled yogurt on my new car's car seat and I have no idea what is the best or the worst way to clean it. I have a few ideas in my mind from Google search and some YouTube videos that I saw but not too sure which one of these is the best practice:

1. Can I simply use furniture wipes to clean it without damaging the seat material?
2. Can I use a wet cloth to clean it?
3. Should I use any special leather friendly material to clean?

Any suggestions?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman Trying solutions randomly might mess things up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saddle soap and warm water is a good way to clean leather. Dampen a cloth and wash/clean in a circular motion. Use a dry cloth to wipe up the soap and water and then another damp cloth to wash off the remains of the soap. A dry cloth to wipe up any remaining water and allow to dry naturally without direct sunlight on it. Once dry give the seat a rub over with a leather conditioner.

Answer (score 1):

My kid spilled her yogurt pouch all over our leather car seats. Some dawn dish soap and scrubbing with a cold, wet cloth got it right up!